# Authorization Using Form Requests in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am having trouble getting the $id of the post to pass to the form request when checking to see if the person editing owns the post. "Job" would be a job posting.   Below is the logic in the JobsRequest.

```
public function authorize()
{
    $job=Job::find($this->id);
    if($job->user_id == Auth::user()->id){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

The above keeps returning as false.  The update method in the controller is below

```
public function update(JobsRequest $request, $id)
{

    $job=Job::find($id);
    $job_data=$request->all();
    $job->update($job_data);

    return redirect('/jobs/'.$job->id.'/edit');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To grab the id within the `FormRequest` object, you'd need to use the following...

```
$id = $this->route('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which gets the id from the route parameter.

```
public function authorize(){ 

    $job_id = $this->route('id');

    $job=Job::find($job_id);
    $user = $this->user();

    if($job->user_id == $user->id) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is in the Low Quality Queue.  Please enhance your answer by adding a description about how/why this works.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta please what is low quality queue?

Comment: The system automatically determines that some posts are not of good quality.  These are then reviewed by a number of users with sufficient rep.  If three of them vote to delete it then it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AuthServiceProvider.php and write

```
 $gate->define('show-product',function($user,$product){
        return $user->id==$product->customer_id;
    });
```

Then write your controller

```
$product= Product::find($id);
        Auth::loginUsingId(3);
        //Auth::logout();
        if(Gate::denies('update',$product)){
            App::abort('404','Product Not Found');
            }
       // $this->authorize('update',$product);
        return $product->name;
```

I think It's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I got this straight from the docs.. This worked for me.

```
$jobId = $this->route('jobs');
return Job::where('id', $jobId)
          ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
```